# Create Calculated Column with Last Reference in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, dax

I'm working with the below schema of tables in Power BI:

`dEquipments`

| Serial Number | Model |
| --- | --- |
| Cell 1 | Cell 2 |
| Cell 3 | Cell 4 |

`fPlacesOfInstallation`

| Reference | Serial Number |
| --- | --- |
| cell 1 (mmm/yy) | cell 2 |
| cell 3 (mmm/yy) | cell 4 |

`dCalendar`

| Date | Reference |
| --- | --- |
| cell 1 | cell 2 (mmm/yy) |
| cell 3 | cell 4 (mmm/yy) |

And I'm trying to create a calculated column in my `dEquipments` table that should return the last place of installation of the row Serial Number.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Instead of saying a non-sentence such as "I tried different approaches", [edit] to say *which* approaches you tried. That way, we can actually help you understand why those didn't work and fix your code, rather than writing it for you.

Answer (score 0):

```
YourNewColumn =
  var thisSN = [Serial Number]
  RETURN CALCULATE(
    LASTDATE('fPlacesOfInstallation'[Reference]),
    ALL('fPlacesOfInstallation'), 'fPlacesOfInstallation'[Serial Number] = thisSN
  )
```

Or if `[Reference]` isn't a date and that the rows are in order with the latest being at the bottom then you can use:

```
YourNewColumn =
  var thisSN = [Serial Number]
  RETURN CALCULATE(
    LASTNONBLANK('fPlacesOfInstallation'[Reference], 1),
    ALL('fPlacesOfInstallation'), 'fPlacesOfInstallation'[Serial Number] = thisSN
  )
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, Sam! The problem is that my REFERENCE column is of type TEXT, not DATE.

Comment: Can it be assumed that it is in order? Ie the last row is the latest? If so, I've updated the answer with that option.